# Does the category of representations over an augmented algebra over a commutative ring have enough projectives?

Tags: lie-algebras, homological-algebra

I think it would be easier to begin with my motivation. Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $\mathfrak{g}$ a Lie algebra over $R$. In Weibel's *Homological algebra* he states that the category of $\mathfrak{g}$-representations (which he calls $\mathfrak{g}$-modules; they are $R$-modules with a $\mathfrak{g}$ action compatible with the $[,]$ of $\mathfrak{g}$) has enough projectives and injectives. To prove this, he shows that the category of representations over $\mathfrak{g}$ and the category of representations over $U\mathfrak{g}$ are naturally isomorphic, where $U\mathfrak{g}$ is the universal enveloping algebra.

He claims this is enough, but I don't understand why. I turned to Cartan & Eilenberg, where they make the argument that, because $U\mathfrak{g}$ is an augmented $R$-algebra, we can compute for example $Tor_n^{U\mathfrak{g}}(A, R)$ for any $A$ a left $U\mathfrak{g}$ module by using a projective resolution of $R$ as a $U\mathfrak{g}$ module. This is only useful for defining homology as such. But does it show that the category of $U\mathfrak{g}$-representations has enough projective objects (which is required for Weibel's definition, since he uses another derived functor)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The category of modules over any ring has enough projectives and injectives.  (For projectives this is very easy: a free module is projective and every module is a quotient of a free module by taking any generating set.)  So, since $U\mathfrak{g}$ is a ring, you are done.

Comment: From what I understand, Weibel works in section 7.2 in the category of $\mathbb{g}$ representations, which are $R$-modules which also have an action by $\mathbb{g}$ compatible with the Lie product in $\mathbb{g}$.

Comment: But then he proves that category is isomorphic to the category of $U\mathfrak{g}$-modules.

Comment: Yes, but by $U\mathfrak{g}$-modules he understands what I called representations for clarity. Actually, he says more: that $U\mathfrak{g}$ is a projective object in $\mathfrak{g}$-representations ($\mathfrak{g}$-mod there).

Comment: No, a $U\mathfrak{g}$-module is just a module over the ring $U\mathfrak{g}$ in the ordinary sense.  It does *not* refer to a representation of $U\mathfrak{g}$ as a Lie algebra.

Comment: So he uses "-**mod** " to refer to representations in the case of $\mathfrak{g}$ and to modules over the ring $U\mathfrak{g}$ in the case of $U\mathfrak{g}$? I am sorry for being persistent, I'm probably misunderstanding something badly, but if it is like I'm asking then the proof of Theorem 7.3.3 doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I don't have Weibel's book so I don't know exactly what he says, but the category of $U\mathfrak{g}$-modules definitely refers to modules in the ordinary ring sense in this context.